# Getting error The operation was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, httpclient, .net-core-3.1

Any Idea what's wrong with following code?
Getting Error **The operation was canceled.  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled.**
Time to time in calling external third party api

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var jsonRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(req);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                    var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest);
                    content.Headers.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = CacheControlHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache");
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                    if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
                    {
                        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutInSeconds);
                    }
                    response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }                
                obj.HttpResponseCode = response.StatusCode;
                ....
```

I am using .net core 3.1 web api application

Comment: Don't create a new HttpClient for each connection.  That will fail under heavy load situations.

Comment: You mean to use  HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

Comment: No.  Create one HttpClient and use it for all connections, and don't dispose it.  https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: There are many api's call some sync some asyc. some get/some post. Using a single one wouldn't make lock on the call? Also is tehre any advantage of using HttpClientHandler?

Comment: That's not how HttpClient works.  It will do as you expect, you just don't need to use a new one per request.

Comment: Thanks @Neil .Will try it separately with load test and check what happens. So basically it's a only solution for above error?